# How to optimize below code to run faster, size of my dataframe is almost 100,000 data points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
def encoder(expiry_dt,expiry1,expiry2,expiry3):
    if expiry_dt == expiry1:
        return 1
    if expiry_dt == expiry2:
        return 2
    if expiry_dt == expiry3:
        return 3



FINAL['Expiry_encodings'] = FINAL.apply(lambda row: '{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}'.format(row['SYMBOL'],row['INSTRUMENT'],row['STRIKE_PR'],row['OPTION_TYP'], encoder(row['EXPIRY_DT'],
                                                                                                                                             row['Expiry1'],
                                                                                                                                             row['Expiry2'],
                                                                                                                                             row['Expiry3'])), axis =1)
```

The code runs totally fine but its too slow, is there any other alternative to achieve this in less time bound?

[image: Sample Dataframe]

Comment: Could you add a short (10-20 rows) example dataframe? That can help in providing an answer with an example.

Comment: it seems like the whole logic here is choosing a specific column from 'symbol', 'instrument', 'strike_pr' and 'option_typ', based on the three other columns 'Expiry1', 'Expiry2', 'Expiry3'. Correct me if I am wrong. sample data will help alot.

Comment: @MEdwin I think it's even simpler than that: the final (new) column just formats various columns, with an additional 1, 2 or 3 added depending on the value of the EXPIRY_DT and Expiry# columns; unless I've misunderstood the axis=1 part. I'd say that the data structure itself or the code before this should be changed to properly accommodate for that in the first place.

Comment: There seems to be no performance problems in the encoder function. Try to find them in another place.

Comment: @DavidLemon Comparing the OPs code and my solution, I can get speed-up of a factor of 10-20. Of course, with a random dataframe of 100_000 rows, the OPs code just takes 6 seconds anyway on my machine, so "too slow" doesn't actually strike me as a problem. But the OP should indeed clarify if they really profiled just this piece of code as being the slow part.

Comment: I know it's just 6 sec but how can I reduce the run time to say 1 sec or even less, that's what I am looking for. So that overall code is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
FINAL['expiry_number'] = '0'
for c in '321':
    FINAL.loc[FINAL['EXPIRY_DT'] == FINAL['Expiry'+c], 'expiry_number'] = c

FINAL['Expiry_encodings'] = FINAL['SYMBOL'].astype(str) + '_' + \
    FINAL['INSTRUMENT'].astype(str) + '_' + FINAL['STRIKE_PR'].astype(str) + \
    '_' + FINAL['OPTION_TYP'].astype(str) + '_' + FINAL['expiry_number']
```

This avoids the three `if` statements, has a default value (`'0'`) if none of the if statements evaluates to `True`, and avoids all the string formatting; above that, it also avoids the `apply` method with a `lambda`.

Note on the `'321'` order: this reflects the order in which the if-chain in the original code section is evaluated: `'Expiry3'` has the lowest priority, and in my code given here, it is first overridden by #2 and then by #1. The original if-chain would shortcut at #1, given that the highest priority. For example, if `'Expiry1'` and `'Expiry3'` have the same value (equal to `'EXPIRY_DT'`), the assigned value is `1`, not `3`.

Comment: Your code reduced time drastically when i ran over entire dataset. Thanks @9769953

Answer (score 0):

Solution as same as above with slight change,

```
FINAL['expiry_number'] = '0'
    for c in '321':
        FINAL.loc[FINAL['EXPIRY_DT'] == FINAL['Expiry'+c], 'expiry_number'] = c

    FINAL['Expiry_encodings'] = FINAL['SYMBOL'].astype(str) + '_' + \
    FINAL['INSTRUMENT'].astype(str) + '_' + FINAL['STRIKE_PR'].astype(str) + \
    '_' + FINAL['OPTION_TYP'].astype(str) +' _' + FINAL['expiry_number']
```